# can't cast model to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have This ActionMethod:

```
public virtual ActionResult Search(AdvancedSearchViewModel SearchVM)
{
    var Things = _things.SelectAll(ThingType.thing);
    if (SearchVM.AllProvince != true)
        Things = Things.Where(pid => pid.City.ProvinceId == SearchVM.drpProvince && pid.City.Id==SearchVM.City ).ToList();
    if (SearchVM.AllGroup != true)
        Things = Things.Where(gid => gid.SubGroup.MainGroupId == SearchVM.drpGroupId && gid.SubGroup.Id == SearchVM.SubGroup).ToList();
    if (!SearchVM.TitleIsContains)
    Things = Things.Where(title=>title.Title==SearchVM.Title).ToList();
    else
        Things = Things.Where(title => title.Title.Contains( SearchVM.Title)).ToList();
    if (SearchVM.Body.Length > 0)
        Things = Things.Where(model=>model.Description==SearchVM.Body).ToList();
    var ThingList = Things.Select(x => new LastThingViewModel { HasReward = x.IsReward, Id = x.Id, Reward = x.Reward, Title = x.Title, RequestCount = x.Requests.Count });

    return View(MVC.Index.Views.ViewNames.SearchResult, ThingList);
}
```

And SearchResult View Is :

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.Thing.ThingListViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchResult";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Sub.cshtml";
}

<h2>SearchResult</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Shared.Views.ViewNames._ThingList, Model);}
```

And ThingList Partial Is :

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.Thing.ThingListViewModel>
....
....
```

but when I call Search Action , I getting This Error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[DomainModel.Entities.Thing,ViewModel.Thing.LastThingViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ViewModel.Thing.ThingListViewModel]'.

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory. The types don't match.  You're returning a bunch of LastThings where Things are expected.

Comment: @PsarTak If you add `ToList()` here - `return View(MVC.Index.Views.ViewNames.SearchResult, ThingList.ToList());` and just to be sure, in the view change the model to `@model List<ViewModel.Thing.ThingListViewModel>` do you still get the same error?